# What are your favorite additives?

Tags: additives, flavor

What's your favorite thing you add to your brew?

- chocolate
- fruit
- spices
- etc.

I'm mostly interested in additives combined after primary fermentation, but flavors from any stage would be informative.
Thanks.

Comment: This question is way too broad for BrewAdvice's format.

Comment: What if this were worded as, "What are the various additives that brewers use with their beer?"

Comment: +1 Yes, this is a broad question, but it has generated good responses.

Comment: This question has been flagged as off topic and too broad, yet there are 7 answers and generally good feedback, so I'm going to leave it.. That work?

Answer (score 2):

I have added coffee and was really happy with the results. My next brew is going to have vanilla soaked in bourbon added to it, so we will see how that turns out!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually used it yet, but I think chocolate extract is going to be my favorite. I'm in the process of making a Chocolate Oatmeal Stout. I will be adding 2 fluid ounces once it is in the secondary.

Comment: Is the extract better than cocoa powder? I am brewing with Baker's chocolate right now (added to boil), and plan to use a little cocoa in secondary.

Comment: I used both powder and extract in my chocolate stout.  I have not done a side-by-side, but my thinking is that I got more flavor from the cocoa and primarily aroma from the extract.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine made a great pale rye ale with spruce tips.  It was hoppy and spicy!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used too many additives yet, but I like spices a lot. My stout has caraway seeds in it, which are awesome. I add those to the mash tun.

I haven't done it yet, but I'm excited to use coffee. I think a super fresh coffee flavor and aroma will be a lot of fun.

I've also use dried chamomile, which was interesting. Turned out pretty well.

I've never ventured into fresh fruit.

Answer (score 0):

I actually added spiced rum to the boil on my latest batch (a porter).  Its still in the bucket, so we'll see how that turns out.

Comment: Be sure to update when you have tasted it. I'm really interested.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I feel like I could throw a vanilla bean in just about anything dark. I love a subtle creamy vanilla flavor and the aroma it adds is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Honney. Adds sweetness as well as complexity to the finished brew. You have to be carefull to boil it for a while though. Found funny mold like stuff floating in one of my first brews (after drinking half of it)